# Input text with only numbers and one dot rules

Tags: input, numbers

Aloha :)

I have this input:

```
<input type="text" name="title" maxlength="15" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" value="<?=$price ?>">
```

It allows only numbers and one DOT. 
But questions is how to set rule so it would be only possible to have dot in the middle, example: 1.2; 11.23; 1.4634634634; 1241245125.46
So it won't allow to set .0 or 1.
???

Answer (score 0):

Try this one \d+.\d+
Btw. you can test your regex here: https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: try to replace `(/[^0-9.]/g, '')` with `(/\d+.\d+/g, '')`

Comment: Not only not working, but also allows me to add now also !@#$@#$%% :(

Comment: `(/^\d+.\d+$/g, '')` this one should block any other characters.
The ^ sais that the string has to start there so only numbers can apear at first position and $ represents the end of the string so only numbers can be last. And in between numbers there has to be a dot.

Comment: It not allows me to write more then 2-3 symbols and clears everything...